# Not able to get the Post data while API testing using Fiddler

Tags: c#

I have this very simple C# AsyncController named "APIController" as:

```
public class APIController : AsyncController{
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public string HelloWorld(Testing t)
{
    return t.Name + " " + t.LastName;
}}
```

And

```
public class Testing
{
    [Required]
    public string Name;
    [Required]
    public string LastName;
}
```

And its accessible 
https://localhost:5958/mvc/api/HelloWorld

But when I’m trying to test using the Fiddler, I’m not able to get the data.Please refer the attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: added the same but sill not getting data(parameter is null)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the method signature to:
public string HelloWorld([FromBody] Testing t)
This will retrieve the data from the request body

And in the request header:
Content-Type: application/json
From Harini2017 answer

Hope this helps